# Is there a way to conditionally sum date ranges in an Access SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table "ORDERHIST" containing transaction data with client IDs, date of purchase, date payment was received, different transaction types, and the invoice amount. I'm trying to create a table that shows the sum of all outstanding invoice amounts for each business day. I only want transactions with a TypeCode of SERV or CONS included in the query.

Data sample:

```
CliendID    PurchaseDate    PaymentDate TypeCode    InvoiceAmt
ID1         1/3/2019        1/4/2019    SERV        430
ID2         1/3/2019        1/4/2019    PART        200
ID1         1/4/2019        1/9/2019    SERV        480
ID3         1/7/2019        1/8/2019    CONS        140
ID2         1/7/2019        1/9/2019    CONS        180
ID3         1/8/2019        1/9/2019    SERV        250
ID1         1/9/2019        1/10/2019   CONS        180
```

Essentially the logic should be sum if (PurchaseDate <= Date) and (PaymentDate >= Date) and (TypeCode = SERV or TypeCode = CONS).

Expected Result:

```
Date        OutstandingBal
1/3/2019    430
1/4/2019    910
1/7/2019    800
1/8/2019    1050
1/9/2019    1090
```

The resulting table dates can either be every day or only on days with transactions, whichever is easier.

Comment: Can you explain what is Date in this logic?

Comment: When I tried creating a solution "Date" was the result of a Group By on PurchaseDate, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to populate the date field. Basically date would be each unique date for PurchaseDate

Comment: In the expected result for 1/9/2019 the sum 1090 is calculated by 3 values 480, 180, 250 where PaymentDate = 1/9/2019 and 1 value 180 where PurchaseDate = 1/9/2019. Is this right? If yes then maybe Date is not strictly PurchaseDate.

Comment: It isn't strictly PurchaseDate, but it is a sum of all outstanding balances for each date with a transaction. For example, no purchases were made on 1/5/19, so "Date" does not include that value. But on 1/7/19, a purchase was made so that is included in the result. The goal is to show an updated amount of "accounts receivable" for each date with transaction history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  You need to start with a list of dates.  Then I would go for a correlated subquery in MS Access:

```
select d.dte,
       (select sum(oh2.invoiceamt)
        from orderhist as oh2
        where oh2.PurchaseDate <= d.dte and
              oh2.PaymentDate >= d.dte and
              oh2.TypeCode in ("SERV", "CONS")
       ) as outstandingbalance
from (select distinct purchasedate as dte
      from orderhist
     ) as d
group by d.dte;
```

Comment: This works! The only issue I had was it seemed to be pretty computationally intensive. My ORDERHIST table is itself a result of another query, would that slow things down?

Comment: @scott . . . Alas, this is computationally intensive.  Unfortunately, MS Access is not very powerful as far as databases go, so your only alternative would be to use a cursor and accumulate the information day-by-day.  If you have access to another database, you can ask a question about how to make this go faster.

Answer (score 0):

OutstandingBal=sum(iif((PurchaseDate <= Date) and (PaymentDate >= Date) and (TypeCode = SERV or TypeCode = CONS), invoiceAmt,0))